# How to blocking iframes in internet explorer or .NET webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, iframe, webbrowser-control

I need some help to blocking iframes in internet explorer or .NET webbrowser control. I tried security preferences, that doesn't worked. XP and IE8, with .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: You could modify the DOM by removing IFRAMEs in some loading/loaded event.

Comment: Could You link me some good tutorial or something? I don't know DOM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `DocumentCompleted` event for your `WebBrowser`, simply remove all the `<iframe>` elements:

```
foreach(HtmlElement x in ((WebBrowser) sender).Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
    x.OuterHtml = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: +1 The OP wants a solution for IE, too. My idea was to search for such an option among Internet Feature Controls, but could not find any. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: short, easy and working! Thanks for that, this solved my problem!

Comment: +1. This is likely the best possible approximation. Note that one need to run this code periodically while page is loaded to remove IFrames created by JavaScript (or disable scripts altogether).